# Can a @Module create an object with a reference to the corresponding @Component?

Tags: dagger-2

I have a class called `FooManager` that is provided by `AppModule`.  `FooManager` dynamically creates instances of classes that implement `Foo`.  The only place those objects are ever referred to by their actual class is within the objects themselves.  Therefore, `Foo` has an init method that receives the `AppComponent` so each `Foo` can inject its own dependencies.

Is it possible for `AppModule` to construct `FooManager` with a reference to `AppComponent`?

Comment: Can you please show some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the obvious, and it worked:

```
@Provides
@AppScope
FooManager provideFooManager(final Context context, final AppComponent component) {
    return new FooManager(context, component);
}
```

There is no `@Provides` method for the `AppComponent`.